# Eclipse Android SDK stopped seeing my Samsung Galaxy S4 device via a USB connection

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, samsung-mobile

A while back I started playing around with Android developing on my PC and used my Samsung Galaxy s4 as the test device and it worked fine.  Once school started I mainly used my laptop and was also able to use my phone on it as well, and still am able to do so.

For some reason, my PC will no longer sees my phone as a running Android device and I cannot figure out why.  I even tried reinstalling the driver to no avail.  Does anyone have any idea as to why this is or any suggestions that I can do to make it be seen again?

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like USB debugging was unchecked.  Go figure it was something simple.